# Can anyboard produced by the chessboard package be exported to svg?

Tags: svg, chessboard

Can any board produced by the chessboard package be exported to svg?

Comment: there is an example here https://davidcarlisle.github.io/latexcgi/test2-make4ht which creates quite good svg but it uses two local .4ht files, so you can't run this locally.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `pdf2svg`. An alternative is `dvisvgm` with WOFF font embedding, but it needs some postprocessing.

LaTeX MWE (from the [chessboard manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf), page 15):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\def\whitepieces{kc3, nc2, pa2, Pd4}
\chessboard[setwhite=\whitepieces,
addblack={Kc8,bh7, pa7}]
\end{document}
```

Compile as follows (in the terminal):

```
pdflatex chessconv.tex
pdf2svg chessconv.pdf chessconv.svg
```

The result is the same as the final screenshot for `dvisvgm` below but with some more padding.

---

For `dvisvgm` you need to compile with `latex` to get a dvi file (so do not compile with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`). Then convert the dvi file with woff font embedding. Terminal commands:

```
latex chessconv.tex
dvisvgm --font-format=woff chessconv.dvi
```

Then open with a web browser:

[image]

So: it is not bad but the `0` character (empty white square) is not encoded correctly. Looking at the generated svg, for example for the top row:

```xml
<text class='f0' x='86.674969' y='85.678583'>8</text>
<text class='f1' x='96.637609' y='92.652553'>0<tspan x='116.562889'>Z</tspan>
<tspan x='136.488169'>k</tspan>
<tspan x='156.41345'>Z</tspan>
<tspan x='176.33873'>0</tspan>
<tspan x='196.26401'>Z</tspan>
<tspan x='216.18929'>0</tspan>
<tspan x='236.11457'>Z</tspan>
</text>
```

The code shows the row label `8` followed by the string `0ZkZ0Z0Z`, in which `0` is an empty white square, `Z` is an empty black square, and `k` is the black king. With a regex find and replace it is not difficult to remove the misrendered `0` characters, to get the following result for this row:

```xml
<text class='f0' x='86.674969' y='85.678583'>8</text>
<text class='f1' x='96.637609' y='92.652553'><tspan x='116.562889'>Z</tspan>
<tspan x='136.488169'>k</tspan>
<tspan x='156.41345'>Z</tspan>
<tspan x='196.26401'>Z</tspan>
<tspan x='236.11457'>Z</tspan>
</text>
```

Removing the `0` throughout the file gives the following result in the browser:

[image]

Comment: I ran the output of your document through [pdf2svg](http://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) and it worked fine the first time without the need for any manual tweaking. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) did well too provided I used the Cairo import rather than the native one.

Comment: @frabjous I did not know pdf2svg existed, but indeed that is much easier, I added it to the answer. The resulting svg code is also quite readable.